# Start application as root at boot time on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, root, startup, upstart

I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04 I have an C++ application which I have compiled. I get the executable which name is "program". Well the thing is that this program use opencv and sockets then if I try to execute it in the terminal like this:

```
./program
```

I got this error:

```
 listener: socket: Operation not permitted
 setsockopt: Bad file descriptor
```

This error appear because I using socket and I need to run my application as root, so I typed this:

```
sudo ./program
```

This request my password and the program works property.

The thing is that I want to run this "program" automatically when I start my Ubuntu, but it does not work. I have another application the name is "camera" which only uses opencv, no socket, then I do not need to run as root. So I put this application in the startup application of Ubuntu and the "camera" application start at the beginning without problem.

So how can I automatic start an application which uses sockets in Ubuntu?

I tried to do this:

```
sudo chown root:root ./program
sudo chmod a+s ./program
```

But my program uses video so then when I try to watch the video the program stops. This is due my program is not free of security holes, so that they're vulnerable to buffer overflow exploits, etc.

Basically I just need to know how can I throw my program as start up without problem.

Comment: You need to provide more details. We can't help you with both an anonymous "program" and no source code at the same time. We need to know one or the other at least. We don't need *all* of the code, just the code around where the error occurs, which appears to be a `socket()` call. It *may* be enough to provide the tail end of the results of `strace -e socket ./program`, again assuming that the error occurs on a `socket()` call, and not something else.

Comment: Hi Warren many thanks for your quick answer. My program uses the socket because I use the RecvRawEth.c file for recieves ethernet data. As I said above I just want to automatic start my application, and (In my opinion, that is maybe wrong) I need to start the program as root, because If I want to use sockets I need it. I edited the answer, I hope can help. Many thanks again

Comment: Is your program is using a port lower than 1024? Those ports are supposed to be used by well known daemons with root permision. Have you tried using a higer port lik 6666 or something? I think those ports are accessible without the need of root permision.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `RecvRawEth.c` file name you posted in your comment above, I'm guessing that you're attempting to use raw sockets (`SOCK_RAW`). This *always* requires that the program be run as root because raw sockets have the potential to let you bypass other security mechanisms, such as the restriction on [privileged ports](http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html).

You really should re-think this application. *Very* few programs legitimately require raw sockets. There is almost always a better way.

You're throwing at least two additional problems into the mix, which really is [not kosher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on Stack Exchange type sites, but I will address them anyway:

1. **setuid `root`**

   You are attempting to get around the restriction on raw sockets by marking it to run as `root` no matter who actually started it. You are potentially opening up one or more security holes by doing this. Trust me: decades of Unix history tell us that complicated setuid `root` programs are likely to have exploitable problems. It can take many years to find and excise all of them.

   If you absolutely must use raw sockets and thus need some element of the program to run as root, it's best to write it as a limited-scope [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)). That is to say, make the program as small as possible, doing only the absolute bare minimum you must do as `root`, plus whatever is necessary to export the resulting information to a program running with normal privileges.
2. **Start on boot**

   If you create a daemon, setting it up to run on system boot is trivial. Any decent tutorial showing you how to create a daemon will go into this. On Ubuntu, I believe this means dealing with [`systemd`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd).

   As for the GUI piece, you simply need to [add it to the session startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup).

Comment: Hi Warren do you mean that I need to split my program in two pieces?. The thing is that I was using this exactly program in an ARM, in which I started it at the boot without problem. The thing is that when I switch the ARM on always I start as root, then I can run my application on boot. Could I do something similar here?

Comment: @user3766585: Yes, splitting the app into two parts — a `root` daemon and a non-privileged GUI part — is one solution to the problem. Ubuntu purposely does not enable the `root` account for interactive logins, again for security reasons. While you could "fix" this, you may be better off choosing a different Linux distro to base your app on. If this app needs to start up and completely take over the entire system, that's more of a kiosk type application, which means you probably need to customize the whole OS startup, which is more of an Arch type application than an Ubuntu one.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Warren, but just let me undestand, It does mean that if I use an application which uses socket I can not start it automatic from my user account? Do I have to split the program in two part one with root privileged?? and all of this is because I using sockets???

Comment: So I mean there is no way to do somenthing like "sudo ./myprogram" in some script if I using sockets?

Comment: @user3766585: Of course you can do that. *If*, that is, you're willing to rip out a bunch of the things that make Ubuntu the way it is, and replace them with custom mechanisms. That is why I suggested Arch: it is designed for this sort of highly-customized setup.

Comment: I can not change to arch, I aware that this is the best way but I can not do it. Where can I get information about how to do what you say?. And for example I just going to use this "computer" for run this program, If I just want to use this computer for this, could be bad idea to activate the root account, and work always as root?

Comment: @user3766585: This is not the appropriate forum to find someone to teach you how to rework Ubuntu's boot and security systems to meet your needs. Honestly, the best way to learn how to do that is to build what you need up from scratch on something like Arch. Then you will have the grounding you need to go and tear Ubuntu apart, and rebuild it.

Comment: Ubuntu has decided to switch to systemd, but 14.04 is still on Upstart.